# Trouble designing a nosql database that needs to store a relationship between people and the tasks they accomplished

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I'm trying to use a NoSql database MongoDB (for personal learning of nosql) and at the moment I'm having trouble with how to organize data.

I have a list of people who are suppose to be doing set tasks from a list of tasks, now what I want to create is an application that shows each person which tasks from a list they have completed and what tasks still remain to be completed.

Normally in a sql database this is becomes

[Person] -> [PersonTask] -> [Task]

Now for a nosql solution I'm not sure how to organize the data, do I

a) Have a collection of tasks, and a collection of people and each person has a list of task id's that they have completed.

b) Have a collection of tasks, and a collection of people and each person includes the tasks they have completed.

c) Do I need to rephrase the problem to work correctly in a nosql environment

d) Is this just a traditional sql problem and it doesn't work any other way

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have less experience with MongoDB than with a few other solutions such as CouchDB.

But what I think I'd do is create just the two entities, "Users" and "Tasks", and put the collection of people assigned on the task object.  Mostly because I think it's more natural to want to look at all the assignments for a task at any give time, plus you may want to do other fancy things when displaying all tasks a person is assigned to such as ordering by due date or urgency or something.

I'd then make a view into task objects that returns all tasks with a specific person assigned.

Comment: MongoDB doesn't have views. I think the equivalent to what you are suggesting is virtual collections, but that has not been implemented yet: http://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-142

Answer (score 0):

In the several NoSql db's I've looked at, they are more or less document oriented, so you could think of things as a DOM, where your person document could have one or more task children. I've complained long and hard that NoSql is really not what these systems should be called, instead they should be NoRelations....but I guess that doesn't sound as cool.